# STM32H7 - IAR Placing Local Variables into 'Reserved Memory' (0x1FF20000 - 0x1FFFFFFF)

Tags: stm32, iar

I started a new project using an STM32H7, currently using IAR EWARM V8, used the STM32CUBEMX to generate the configuration code, and get an initial project going.

I worked through a couple of the CUBEMX eval projects to get some hardware verified and working, and am able to step through code fine.

But there is something odd going on, in particular with variables if you assign them as local vars within a function, somehow IAR is placing them into the 'System Reserved' memory range...

ie within `0x1FF20000` - `0x1FFFFFFF`

For example... the project example 'FMC_NOR' that STM provides, is test code for testing our a NOR flash, etc..

they created these two small arrays as globals vars just at the top of the `main.c` file.
(`buffer_size` is 0x1000)

```
uint16_t aTxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint16_t aRxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
```

When in the global space, they are allocated in the DTCM region (0x2000:0000)

When moved as local vars, they then become allocated into the 'reserved space'...

What happens is, when IAR encounters any arrays like this, the processor faults with an 'imprecise data access' hardware fault.

This same error occurs with code to initialize the JPEG module, as it attempts to load the arrays of Huffman tables, etc...

When using TrueStudio this problem does not occur... CubeMX auto-generates the linker files for whichever compiler you are using.

I didn't specifically see anything in the linker files pointing to the reserved memory address.

So not sure what could be going on?  I'm new to using this processor, so I'm just starting to understand it's memory mapping.

Thanks for any help or suggestions, I'd like to get IAR figured out, as so far I like it a bit over TrueStudio.

Comment: your "small arrays" are 8192 B each. And your stack size is probably 512B. you try to place the 16KB data into probably 0.5kB space. If the stack is located on the top of RAM segment the start address of the array will be outside this segment. So if you try to access it you get the hard fault.  gcc based startups place the stack on the bottom of the RAM segment. So you just silently overflow the stack

Comment: Yeah, so I assumed the stack was the problem with these arrays...

Comment: But the same problem occurs with the JPEG module init... there are a bunch of const Huffman tables declared in global memory....

but under IAR this jpeg init throws the same 'imprecise data access' at this spot:

if(JPEG_Set_HuffEnc_Mem(hjpeg, (JPEG_ACHuffTableTypeDef *)acLum_huffmanTableAddr, (JPEG_DCHuffTableTypeDef *)dcLum_huffmanTableAddr, (JPEG_ACHuffTableTypeDef *)acChrom_huffmanTableAddr, (JPEG_DCHuffTableTypeDef *)dcChrom_huffmanTableAddr) != HAL_OK)
  {
    hjpeg->ErrorCode = HAL_JPEG_ERROR_HUFF_TABLE;
    
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

Comment: I did not do any mods to this routine, so whatever IAR is doing, these arrays are either unaligned or again in an incorrect memory location?

Comment: Sorry mate - you need to learn a bit to do this kind of projects. I cant teach you online or debug your code.

Comment: no worries, I'm not a newb to embedded, been doing dev and RE work for 20+ years..  just new to this processor, 

The stack question was dumb, was just funny that TrueStudio is doing something different...

Comment: The JPEG problem is real, I'm debugging and tracking down where it's occurring, these arrays are just in the correct spot in flash.. 

just tracking down the error

Comment: Yep, one of the rounds of the 'JPEG_Set_HuffAC_Mem' is ending up trying to write to reserved memory, when it's supposed to be writing to the JPEG module periph. memory... 

but somewhere the pointer is getting screwed up... and this is not me, this is not code I modified, this is all init code generated by CubeMx...

(nothing to do with the stack stuff I mentioned above, that's not even part of this startup init. sequence.. that was test code)

Comment: Anyhow, my real questions were just regarding IAR and TrueStudio, and if anyone was aware of any settings that could affect placement of globals, etc...

the linker files are one thing, but IAR also has some things like --nounaligned and other cmd line options like that

but so far, deep in their JPEG init code one of their setup loops eventually overwrites its own data of table pointers, so then it's fubar from there...

I'll figure it out... but there are certainly some IAR things are are different from using TrueStudio/Gcc...

Comment: Ok, I found the problem...

definitely an issue with CubeMX and their IAR generation code..

their linker file sets the stack size to 1k (0x400)...

Their JPEG init function (JPEG_ACHuff_BitsVals_To_SizeCodes) needs more than that on the stack for their huff init arrays... so during the init of these arrays they walk right over the handle for the JPEG instance, and then blows everything up...

I'll probably let STM know that they should probably fix this in their code gen for IAR...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own question... so no longer need help on this...

This is in the 'stm32h743xx_flash.icf' generated by STM CUBEMX for the STM32H7...

```
/*-Sizes-*/
define symbol __ICFEDIT_size_cstack__ = 0x400;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_size_heap__ = 0x200;
/**** End of ICF editor section. ###ICF###*/
```

Bumped the 'size_cstack' up to 2k (0x800) and everything is fine...

Comment: Also, just to add some more details, this is what I meant about 'IAR vs True Studio'

TrueStudio has a 'min stack' & 'min heap' size in their linker files, so obviously when they ran the gcc compiler it adjusted the stack according to the memory needed by the written code...

whereas IAR just compiled it strictly by the 'size_cstack', even though the written code needed more.. it just let the compiled code run it over...

So that is why it all makes sense now between the two..